# automation input to read command in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, automation

I want to give input to one shell script from another shell script

```
#|bin/bash
echo "enter y/n"
read r
echo $r
```

I am sending input using

```
echo -e 'y' > /proc/10840/fd/1
```

But it display only on console. it does not take as input of read command.

Answer (score 0):

The STDIN of the script is bound to its the terminal, so that you cannot write to it from outside. You can use FIFOs for this. The general idea is:

1. Script starts and creates a FIFO (or the FIFO can be created before from the command line)
2. Script opens FIFO for readings and reads the data in a loop.
3. From outside you can write to the FIFO, then the written content will be read by the script in its loop.

Reference: `man fifo` : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html

Comment: if i am run program such that it wait input on tty than is it possible to give input?

Comment: Only if the STDIN of the program is the STDOUT of another program (man PIPE). But then only the writting program of the pipe can give input to the reading program. Otherwise - no.